# Apache Not Starting

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2, port

I can't seem to start Apache 2.2 on Windows7 listening on ports 80 and 8443.

I get the following error:

> > > (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8443     .

This error is usually caused by another app listening on the same port but I definitely don't have another application listening on port 8443.

I get this error no matter what port I tell ssl to listen on.

Any ideas?

Netstat dump:

Active Connections

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       872
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3500
 [magentproc.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1025           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       508
 [wininit.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1026           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       988
  eventlog
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1027           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       472
  Schedule
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1028           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       580
 [lsass.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1029           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       556
 [services.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5001           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3500
 [magentproc.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5002           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3500
 [magentproc.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5003           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3500
 [magentproc.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:50500          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3500
 [magentproc.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:54345          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3500
 [magentproc.exe]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:139      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28530    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     4172
 [OUTLOOK.EXE]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28532    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     4172
 [OUTLOOK.EXE]
 TCP    10.125.247.11:28555    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     4172
  [OUTLOOK.EXE]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28556    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     4172
 [OUTLOOK.EXE]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28560    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     4172
 [OUTLOOK.EXE]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28563    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     4172
 [OUTLOOK.EXE]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28564    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     3724
[communicator.exe]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28567    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     4172
 [OUTLOOK.EXE]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28571    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     4172
 [OUTLOOK.EXE]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28582    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     4172
 [OUTLOOK.EXE]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28584    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     4172
 [OUTLOOK.EXE]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28603    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     4172
 [OUTLOOK.EXE]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28607    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     4172
 [OUTLOOK.EXE]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28667    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     3724
 [communicator.exe]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:28669    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     3724
 [communicator.exe]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:29482    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     1692
 [chrome.exe]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:29486    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     1692
 [ chrome.exe]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:29489    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     1692
 [chrome.exe]
  TCP    10.125.247.11:29491    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     1692
   [chrome.exe]
    TCP    10.125.247.11:29493    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     1692
   [chrome.exe]
    TCP    10.125.247.11:29495    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     1692
   [chrome.exe]
    TCP    10.125.247.11:29498    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     1692
   [chrome.exe]
    TCP    10.125.247.11:29502    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     1692
   [chrome.exe]
    TCP    10.125.247.11:29505    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     1692
  [chrome.exe]
    TCP    10.125.247.11:29509    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     1692
   [chrome.exe]
    TCP    10.125.247.11:29513    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     1692
   [chrome.exe]
    TCP    10.125.247.11:29514    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     1692
   [chrome.exe]
    TCP    10.125.247.11:29515    172.19.41.40:8080      ESTABLISHED     1692
   [chrome.exe]
    TCP    127.0.0.1:1033         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3212
   [AccentureMobileMediaReminderClient.exe]
    TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
   Can not obtain ownership information
    TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING       872
    RpcSs
   [svchost.exe]
    TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
   Can not obtain ownership information
    TCP    [::]:1025              [::]:0                 LISTENING       508
   [wininit.exe]
    TCP    [::]:1026              [::]:0                 LISTENING       988
    eventlog
   [svchost.exe]
    TCP    [::]:1027              [::]:0                 LISTENING       472
    Schedule
   [svchost.exe]
    TCP    [::]:1028              [::]:0                 LISTENING       580
   [lsass.exe]
    TCP    [::]:1029              [::]:0                 LISTENING       556
   [services.exe]
    TCP    [::]:5357              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
   Can not obtain ownership information
    TCP    [::]:8000              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
   Can not obtain ownership information
    UDP    0.0.0.0:123            *:*                                    1064
    W32Time
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*                                    472
    IKEEXT
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                                    1064
    EventSystem
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                                    1064
    EventSystem
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                                    2276
    PeerDistSvc
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                                    1064
    EventSystem
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                                    2276
    PeerDistSvc
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                                    1064
    EventSystem
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*                                    472
    IKEEXT
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                                    1228
    Dnscache
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    0.0.0.0:55306          *:*                                    1064
    EventSystem
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    0.0.0.0:55308          *:*                                    1064
    EventSystem
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    10.125.247.11:137      *:*                                    4
   Can not obtain ownership information
    UDP    10.125.247.11:138      *:*                                    4
   Can not obtain ownership information
    UDP    10.125.247.11:1900     *:*                                    3952
    SSDPSRV
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    10.125.247.11:62526    *:*                                    3952
    SSDPSRV
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                                    3952
    SSDPSRV
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    127.0.0.1:53356        *:*                                    2644
   [taskhost.exe]
    UDP    127.0.0.1:56632        *:*                                    580
   [lsass.exe]
    UDP    127.0.0.1:57319        *:*                                    3724
   [communicator.exe]
    UDP    127.0.0.1:60703        *:*                                    3724
   [communicator.exe]
    UDP    127.0.0.1:62527        *:*                                    3952
    SSDPSRV
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    127.0.0.1:63140        *:*                                    4172
   [OUTLOOK.EXE]
    UDP    [::]:123               *:*                                    1064
    W32Time
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [::]:500               *:*                                    472
    IKEEXT
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    1064
    EventSystem
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    2276
    PeerDistSvc
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    1064
    EventSystem
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    1064
    EventSystem
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    2276
    PeerDistSvc
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    1064
    EventSystem
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [::]:4500              *:*                                    472
    IKEEXT
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [::]:5355              *:*                                    1228
    Dnscache
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [::]:55307             *:*                                    1064
    EventSystem
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [::]:55309             *:*                                    1064
    EventSystem
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*                                    3952
    SSDPSRV
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [::1]:62525            *:*                                    3952
    SSDPSRV
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [fe80::cca:bedf:a696:8354%13]:546  *:*                                                988
    Dhcp
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [fe80::cca:bedf:a696:8354%13]:1900  *:*                                          3952
    SSDPSRV
   [svchost.exe]
    UDP    [fe80::cca:bedf:a696:8354%13]:62524  *:*                                    3952
    SSDPSRV
   [svchost.exe]
```

Comment: You almost certainly have. Run `netstat -oban` to see what program is listening there.

Comment: As my netstat dump shows; I do not.

Comment: @edgarnwin Possibly a misconfiguration of apache then. Have you tried changing the port (`Listen` directive) and see if that makes any difference? If it does, is it still also listening on the problematic port?

Comment: I change the SSL/8443 port and I still get the same problem no matter what port I change it to.

Answer (score 0):

it cetainly  looks that way .. now this is a long shot,, but check your /etc/services and see if the 8443 port is defined?

```
pcsync-https    8443/tcp    # PCsync HTTPS
pcsync-https    8443/udp    # PCsync HTTPS
pcsync-http     8444/tcp    # PCsync HTTP
pcsync-http     8444/udp    # PCsync HTTP
```

Comment: I'm on windows so that file doesn't exist. I don't know what 'certainly looks that way'. My NETSTAT shows that I'm not using port 8443.

Comment: I found the windows version of that file.

Comment: I'm not a windows guy, but have you checked the windows firewall and security stuff??  that stuff can be kinda hairy.

Answer (score 0):

I was told by this:

If you are using the latest Skype, go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> connection. Disable the 'Use port 80 and 443 for alternatve.. '

Sign Out and Close all Skype windows.

---

Thanks for the advice. It Worked!!!